# Looping and Keeping the count

Tags: java, loops

I would like this method called "roll" to count down my int called "spacePoints" each time its called.  It works however, it starts from 100 each time.  I need it to start where the points were left off each time the method is called.

```
int spacePoints = 100; 

public void roll (){  
    pointsRolled = ((int) (Math.random() * 10)+ 1);
    if (pointsRolled % 3 ==0){ 
    System.out.println("You must fight!!!");

    } else {
      spacePoints = spacePoints- pointsRolled;
     System.out.println("You have " + spacePoints + "  to go.");

   }

   }
```

Comment: You have not shown enough code. Nothing shown will make it start at 100 each time `roll()` is called.

Comment: How are you calling the method? From your snippet you have "spacePoints" as a field of the class and are decrementing it by "pointsRolled" when it is not divisible by three.  Unless you are creating a new instance of your class each time you invoke the "roll" method it will "keep track" of the "spacePoints" by that field of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear, as @John3136 mentioned, but I'm betting you need to read more about the static keyword and understand [class members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Comment: Hey,  It seems to be working after using static.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you created multiple instances of the class which contains the method     the `roll()` method. Because otherwise, in the contrary case (a single instance of the class), `spacePoints` value would be modified after each call. 
So, to solve your problem, you should call `roll()` only on the same instance and in this way, `spacePoints` which will be associated to the same instance will be updated from call to call.

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject();
obj.roll();
obj.roll();
obj.roll();
```

Comment: It will never be called if spacePoints is set to 100. Are you sure about your `while` condition ? Edit your question and post more code, it could be helpful.

Comment: That is a mistake.  I meant to say,  while (spacePoints > 0) { game.roll();}